# Cause of ComputerSignature failure in dotnet-passbook

Tags: c#, certificate, signing, passbook

Running the code off github,dotnet-passbook (updated thumbprint to match mine)

```
CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner(SubjectIdentifierType.SubjectKeyIdentifier, passCert)
            {
                IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.None
            };
            signer.Certificates.Add(passCert);
            signer.Certificates.Add(appleCert);
            signer.SignedAttributes.Add(new Pkcs9SigningTime());

            Trace.TraceInformation("Processing the signature..");
       //fails on the next line
            signing.ComputeSignature(signer);
```

I get the following error:

```
Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
HResult: -2146893811
HelpLink: null
IPForWatsonBuckets: {1687357764}
InnerException: null
IsTransient: false
Message: "Key does not exist.\r\n"
RemoteStackTrace: null
Source: "System.Security"
StackTrace: "   at System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignedCms.ComputeSignature(CmsSigner signer, Boolean silent)\r\n   at Passbook.Generator.PassGenerator.SignManifestFile(PassGeneratorRequest request) in D:\\git\\dotnet-passbook\\Passbook.Generator\\PassGenerator.cs:line 261"
TargetSite: {Void ComputeSignature(System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.CmsSigner, Boolean)}
```

I see that there were some bugs with Net4.0 cited elsewhere.

- All Certificates are valid still (and not null)
- All Certificates are from apple

Any quick insight as to cause?

Answer (score 2):

Ken,

I'm the author of dotnet-passbook, so I'll try and help :)

This is usually caused by the fact the private key is missing from the certificate. When you export them, you must be sure to include the private key component. This is required to actually sign the manifest.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, my Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority certificate had expired so I deleted my original one from mmc and replaced it by downloaded a new certificate from here - https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/ However, the dotnet-passbook library now fails with "'Failed to sign manifest'" Any suggestions as to why?

Comment: Does the cert you're using for signing include the private key?

Comment: No, it's exactly the one available at that link.

Comment: Sorry, I mean your own cert. Does that have the private component?

Comment: Yes, my own certificate has the private key. All I've done is replaced my old Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority certificate with the new one released on Feb 2016.

Comment: Hmm, that "Key Not Found" error is usually the result of the private key being missing. If you want to email the cert, I can check on my end?